# Bake a texture to vertex color in Blender 2.8

Tags: baking, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

In Blender 2.8 was removed Blender Render, where was option "Bake Texture to Vertex Color". Unfortunately in Eevee there is no such functionality.
I like new Blender 2.8 very much, but I can't use it without this function.

For baking texture to vertex color I also had used official script `Bake UV-Texture to Vertex Colors`, but in Blender 2.8 was changed API, and script don't work.

As I understand blender developers have removed method `uv_texture` from Blender 2.8.
I've been trying to learn python to make this script work, but I still can't understand how to get RGB color value from UV point on image texture applied to material in node editor?

Maybe someone know how to make this script work, or it's impossible until developers not add bake to vertex color in Eevee?

````py
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####

# <pep8 compliant>

"""
Bake UV-Texture to Vertex Colors Addon

Contact:        p_boelens@msn.com
Information:    http://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=28211

Contributor(s): Patrick Boelens, CoDEmanX.

All rights reserved.
"""

bl_info = {
    "name": "Bake UV-Texture to Vertex Colors",
    "description": "Bakes the colors of the active UV Texture to a Vertex Color layer. ",
    "author": "Patrick Boelens, CoDEmanX",
    "version": (0, 6),
    "blender": (2, 63, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Vertex Paint > Toolshelf > Bake",
    "warning": "Requires image texture, generated textures aren't supported.",
    "wiki_url": "http://wiki.blender.org/index.php?title=Extensions:2.6/"
                "Py/Scripts/UV/Bake_Texture_to_Vertex_Colors",
    "tracker_url": "http://projects.blender.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=28211",
    "category": "UV"}

import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, EnumProperty, FloatVectorProperty
from math import fabs
from colorsys import rgb_to_hsv, hsv_to_rgb

class UV_OT_bake_texture_to_vcols(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "uv.bake_texture_to_vcols"
    bl_label = "Bake UV-Texture to Vertex Colors"
    bl_description = "Bake active UV-Texture to new Vertex Color layer (requires image texture)"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    replace_active_layer = BoolProperty(name="Replace layer",
                                        description="Overwrite active Vertex Color layer",
                                        default=True)

    mappingModes = [("CLIP", "Clip", "Don't affect vertices who's UV-coordinates are out of bounds."),
                    ("REPEAT", "Repeat", "Tile the image so that each vertex is accounted for."),
                    ("EXTEND", "Extend", "Extends the edges of the image to the UV-coordinates.")
                   ]

    mappingMode = EnumProperty(items=mappingModes,
                               default="CLIP",
                               name="Mapping",
                               description="The mode to use for baking vertices who's UV-coordinates are out of bounds.")

    blendingModes = [("MIX", "Mix", ""),
                     ("ADD", "Add", ""),
                     ("SUBTRACT", "Subtract", ""),
                     ("MULTIPLY", "Multiply", ""),
                     ("SCREEN", "Screen", ""),
                     ("OVERLAY", "Overlay", ""),
                     ("DIFFERENCE", "Difference", ""),
                     ("DIVIDE", "Divide", ""),
                     ("DARKEN", "Darken", ""),
                     ("LIGHTEN", "Lighten", ""),
                     ("HUE", "Hue", ""),
                     ("SATURATION", "Saturation", ""),
                     ("VALUE", "Value", ""),
                     ("COLOR", "Color", ""),
                     ("SOFT_LIGHT", "Soft Light", ""),
                     ("LINEAR_LIGHT", "Linear Light", "")
                    ]

    blendingMode = EnumProperty(items=blendingModes,
                                default="MULTIPLY",
                                name="Blend Type",
                                description="The blending mode to use when baking")

    mirror_x = BoolProperty(name="Mirror X", description="Mirror the image on the X-axis.")
    mirror_y = BoolProperty(name="Mirror Y", description="Mirror the image on the Y-axis.")

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return (context.object and
                context.object.type == 'MESH' and 
                context.mode != 'EDIT_MESH' and
                context.object.data.uv_layers.active and
                context.object.data.uv_textures.active)

    def execute(self, context):
        obdata = context.object.data

        if self.replace_active_layer and obdata.vertex_colors.active:
            vertex_colors = obdata.vertex_colors.active
        else:
            vertex_colors = obdata.vertex_colors.new(name="Baked UV texture")

            if not vertex_colors:
                # Can't add more than 17 VCol layers
                self.report({'ERROR'}, "Couldn't add another Vertex Color layer,\n"
                                       "Please remove an existing layer or replace active.")
                return {'CANCELLED'}

        obdata.vertex_colors.active = vertex_colors

        uv_images = {}
        for uv_tex in obdata.uv_textures.active.data:
            if uv_tex.image and uv_tex.image.name not in uv_images and uv_tex.image.pixels:

                uv_images[uv_tex.image.name] = (uv_tex.image.size[0],
                                                uv_tex.image.size[1],
                                                uv_tex.image.pixels[:]
                                                # Accessing pixels directly is far too slow.
                                                # Copied to new array for massive performance-gain.
                                               )

        for p in obdata.polygons:
            img = obdata.uv_textures.active.data[p.index].image
            if not img:
                continue

            image_size_x, image_size_y, uv_pixels = uv_images[img.name]

            for loop in p.loop_indices:

                co = obdata.uv_layers.active.data[loop].uv
                x_co = round(co[0] * (image_size_x - 1))
                y_co = round(co[1] * (image_size_y - 1))

                if x_co < 0 or x_co >= image_size_x or y_co < 0 or y_co >= image_size_y:
                    if self.mappingMode == 'CLIP':
                        continue

                    elif self.mappingMode == 'REPEAT':
                        x_co %= image_size_x
                        y_co %= image_size_y

                    elif self.mappingMode == 'EXTEND':
                        if x_co > image_size_x - 1:
                            x_co = image_size_x - 1
                        if x_co < 0:
                            x_co = 0
                        if y_co > image_size_y - 1:
                            y_co = image_size_y - 1
                        if y_co < 0:
                            y_co = 0

                if self.mirror_x:
                     x_co = image_size_x -1 - x_co

                if self.mirror_y:
                     y_co = image_size_y -1 - y_co

                col_out = vertex_colors.data[loop].color

                pixelNumber = (image_size_x * y_co) + x_co
                r = uv_pixels[pixelNumber*4]
                g = uv_pixels[pixelNumber*4 + 1]
                b = uv_pixels[pixelNumber*4 + 2]
                a = uv_pixels[pixelNumber*4 + 3]

                col_in = r, g, b # texture-color
                col_result = [r,g,b] # existing / 'base' color

                if self.blendingMode == 'MIX':
                    col_result = col_in

                elif self.blendingMode == 'ADD':
                    col_result[0] = col_in[0] + col_out[0]
                    col_result[1] = col_in[1] + col_out[1]
                    col_result[2] = col_in[2] + col_out[2]

                elif self.blendingMode == 'SUBTRACT':
                    col_result[0] = col_in[0] - col_out[0]
                    col_result[1] = col_in[1] - col_out[1]
                    col_result[2] = col_in[2] - col_out[2]

                elif self.blendingMode == 'MULTIPLY':
                    col_result[0] = col_in[0] * col_out[0]
                    col_result[1] = col_in[1] * col_out[1]
                    col_result[2] = col_in[2] * col_out[2]

                elif self.blendingMode == 'SCREEN':
                    col_result[0] = 1 - (1.0 - col_in[0]) * (1.0 - col_out[0])
                    col_result[1] = 1 - (1.0 - col_in[1]) * (1.0 - col_out[1])
                    col_result[2] = 1 - (1.0 - col_in[2]) * (1.0 - col_out[2])

                elif self.blendingMode == 'OVERLAY':
                    if col_out[0] < 0.5:
                        col_result[0] = col_out[0] * (2.0 * col_in[0])
                    else:
                        col_result[0] = 1.0 - (2.0 * (1.0 - col_in[0])) * (1.0 - col_out[0])
                    if col_out[1] < 0.5:
                        col_result[1] = col_out[1] * (2.0 * col_in[1])
                    else:
                        col_result[1] = 1.0 - (2.0 * (1.0 - col_in[1])) * (1.0 - col_out[1])
                    if col_out[2] < 0.5:
                        col_result[2] = col_out[2] * (2.0 * col_in[2])
                    else:
                        col_result[2] = 1.0 - (2.0 * (1.0 - col_in[2])) * (1.0 - col_out[2])

                elif self.blendingMode == 'DIFFERENCE':
                    col_result[0] = fabs(col_in[0] - col_out[0])
                    col_result[1] = fabs(col_in[1] - col_out[1])
                    col_result[2] = fabs(col_in[2] - col_out[2])

                elif self.blendingMode == 'DIVIDE':
                    if(col_in[0] != 0.0):
                        col_result[0] = col_out[0] / col_in[0]
                    if(col_in[1] != 0.0):
                        col_result[0] = col_out[1] / col_in[1]
                    if(col_in[2] != 0.0):
                        col_result[2] = col_out[2] / col_in[2]

                elif self.blendingMode == 'DARKEN':
                    if col_in[0] < col_out[0]:
                        col_result[0] = col_in[0]
                    else:
                        col_result[0] = col_out[0]
                    if col_in[1] < col_out[1]:
                        col_result[1] = col_in[1]
                    else:
                        col_result[1] = col_out[1]
                    if col_in[2] < col_out[2]:
                        col_result[2] = col_in[2]
                    else:
                        col_result[2] = col_out[2]


                elif self.blendingMode == 'LIGHTEN':
                    if col_in[0] > col_out[0]:
                        col_result[0] = col_in[0]
                    else:
                        col_result[0] = col_out[0]
                    if col_in[1] > col_out[1]:
                        col_result[1] = col_in[1]
                    else:
                        col_result[1] = col_out[1]
                    if col_in[2] > col_out[2]:
                        col_result[2] = col_in[2]
                    else:
                        col_result[2] = col_out[2]

                elif self.blendingMode == 'HUE':
                    hsv_in = rgb_to_hsv(col_in[0], col_in[1], col_in[2])
                    hsv_out = rgb_to_hsv(col_out[0], col_out[1], col_out[2])
                    hue = hsv_in[0]
                    col_result = hsv_to_rgb(hue, hsv_out[1], hsv_out[2])

                elif self.blendingMode == 'SATURATION':
                    hsv_in = rgb_to_hsv(col_in[0], col_in[1], col_in[2])
                    hsv_out = rgb_to_hsv(col_out[0], col_out[1], col_out[2])
                    sat = hsv_in[1]
                    col_result = hsv_to_rgb(hsv_out[0], sat, hsv_out[2])

                elif self.blendingMode == 'VALUE':
                    hsv_in = rgb_to_hsv(col_in[0], col_in[1], col_in[2])
                    hsv_out = rgb_to_hsv(col_out[0], col_out[1], col_out[2])
                    val = hsv_in[2]
                    col_result = hsv_to_rgb(hsv_out[0], hsv_out[1], val)

                elif self.blendingMode == 'COLOR':
                    hsv_in = rgb_to_hsv(col_in[0], col_in[1], col_in[2])
                    hsv_out = rgb_to_hsv(col_out[0], col_out[1], col_out[2])
                    hue = hsv_in[0]
                    sat = hsv_in[1]
                    col_result = hsv_to_rgb(hue, sat, hsv_out[2])

                elif self.blendingMode == 'SOFT_LIGHT':
                    scr = 1 - (1.0 - col_in[0]) * (1.0 - col_out[0])
                    scg = 1 - (1.0 - col_in[1]) * (1.0 - col_out[1])
                    scb = 1 - (1.0 - col_in[2]) * (1.0 - col_out[2])

                    col_result[0] = (1.0 - col_out[0]) * (col_in[0] * col_out[0]) + (col_out[0] * scr)
                    col_result[1] = (1.0 - col_out[1]) * (col_in[1] * col_out[1]) + (col_out[1] * scg)
                    col_result[2] = (1.0 - col_out[2]) * (col_in[2] * col_out[2]) + (col_out[2] * scb)


                elif self.blendingMode == 'LINEAR_LIGHT':
                    if col_in[0] > 0.5:
                        col_result[0] = col_out[0] + 2.0 * (col_in[0] - 0.5)
                    else:
                        col_result[0] = col_out[0] + 2.0 * (col_in[0] - 1.0)
                    if col_in[1] > 0.5:
                        col_result[1] = col_out[1] + 2.0 * (col_in[1] - 0.5)
                    else:
                        col_result[1] = col_out[1] + 2.0 * (col_in[1] - 1.0)
                    if col_in[2] > 0.5:
                        col_result[2] = col_out[2] + 2.0 * (col_in[2] - 0.5)
                    else:
                        col_result[2] = col_out[2] + 2.0 * (col_in[2] - 1.0)

                # Add alpha color
                a_inverted = 1 - a
                alpha_color = context.scene.uv_bake_alpha_color
                col_result = (col_result[0] * a + alpha_color[0] * a_inverted,
                              col_result[1] * a + alpha_color[1] * a_inverted,
                              col_result[2] * a + alpha_color[2] * a_inverted)

                vertex_colors.data[loop].color = col_result

        return {'FINISHED'}

class VIEW3D_PT_tools_uv_bake_texture_to_vcols(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Bake"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_options = {'DEFAULT_CLOSED'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(self, context):
        return(context.mode == 'PAINT_VERTEX')

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()
        col.prop(context.scene, "uv_bake_alpha_color")
        col.separator()
        col.operator("uv.bake_texture_to_vcols", text="UV Texture to VCols")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.uv_bake_alpha_color = FloatVectorProperty(name="Alpha Color",
        description="Color to be used for transparency",
        subtype='COLOR',
        min=0.0,
        max=1.0)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.uv_bake_alpha_color

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: you're able to bake texture to vertex color using this script?

Answer (score 10):

It's not as full-featured as the script you've posted, but I've come up with a very simple Bake-UV-to-Vertex-Colors script:

```py
import bpy

def bake_uv_to_vc(image_name):
    # Lookup the image by name. Easier than trying to figure out which one is
    # currently active
    image = bpy.data.images[image_name]

    width = image.size[0]
    height = image.size[1]

    # Keep UVs in the within the bounds to avoid out-of-bounds errors
    def _clamp_uv(val):
        return max(0, min(val, 1))

    # Need to set the mode to VERTEX_PAINT, otherwise the vertex color data is
    # empty for some reason
    ob = bpy.context.object
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='VERTEX_PAINT')

    # Caching the image pixels makes this *much* faster
    local_pixels = list(image.pixels[:])

    for face in ob.data.polygons:
        for vert_idx, loop_idx in zip(face.vertices, face.loop_indices):
            uv_coords = ob.data.uv_layers.active.data[loop_idx].uv

            # Just sample the closest pixel to the UV coordinate. If you need
            # higher quality, an improved approach might be to implement
            # bilinear sampling here instead
            target = [round(_clamp_uv(uv_coords.x) * (width - 1)), round(_clamp_uv(uv_coords.y) * (height - 1))]
            index = ( target[1] * width + target[0] ) * 4

            bpy.context.object.data.vertex_colors["Col"].data[loop_idx].color[0] = local_pixels[index]
            bpy.context.object.data.vertex_colors["Col"].data[loop_idx].color[1] = local_pixels[index + 1]
            bpy.context.object.data.vertex_colors["Col"].data[loop_idx].color[2] = local_pixels[index + 2]
            bpy.context.object.data.vertex_colors["Col"].data[loop_idx].color[3] = local_pixels[index + 3]

bake_uv_to_vc("NAME_OF_THE_IMAGE_TO_BAKE_TO_VC")
```

It's very simple and straight forward. Bake everything to an image. Then run the script, and the closest pixel in the image to each vertex will become the vertext color.

Comment: Thank you for help Zach! Your script is very usefull! But I've already ported the old script for baking to Blender 2.8 api.

Comment: Be careful not to put your uv in bounds, because there will be an index error if a UV is at one of the edges of the UV space.

Comment: Oddly enough, this scrip always fails with 2.81a :( Always getting index out of range error, no matter if I have mesh UV map inside the 0,1 bounds or slightly extending beyond that.

Comment: @motorsep I've added bounds checking to the UV lookup, which seems to fix the problem for me on Blender 2.81a. This also addresses softyoda yoann's concerns.

Comment: @Zach Capalbo Thanks, it seems to be working now. I baked RGBA image to vertex color and all channels (including alpha, or so it seems) show up in UE4, after I exported mesh from Blender into FBX and imported it to UE4 with mesh's vertex colors.

Comment: I've never used a Blender script before, and I get an error message saying to check the console when I try this, but neither the log nor console says anything.

Also, looking at the script above it seems to ask for an image name (which I hope I get to pick from a list) but that never happens to me either.