# How to convert textures into materials per each triangle in blender

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials

Okay so, to be exact

Every model is made up of triangles right?
then when you add a texture to the model, the texture wraps around the model and becomes textured
Now what I want to do is get each triangle and get the texture applied to each triangle and then set it to the average of the texture colors

so let's say there's a triangle which has red and yellow texture
now what will happen is that the orange and yellow will convert into the average of both of them and then turn into a material
so if I load in the model without the texture, i'll still see that there's some representation of a texture

of course, I could assign the color to each triangle individually but that'd be a really long and painful process considering that the meshes are made up of thousands of faces and more

note: forgot to say earlier, im planning on exporting it as .OBJ

[image]

Comment: Hi, no idea :D but i just want to ask for what reason you want to achive this?

Comment: it's for a personal project of importing individual parts without textures

Comment: Would be enough for you to convert image texture into vertex / face color? Like here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41677/2214

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/157784/2214

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not what did you ask for, but might be helpful. Add-on **[Bake to Vertex Color](https://gumroad.com/l/zdgxg)** takes image texture with UV map coordinates and creates (bake) colors into vertex color (you can find it under *Data Properties > Vertex Color*. It doesn't take an average, but certain pixel under vertex.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Note:

- To generate average color usually ends with a braun color :)
- There can be also stored color per face instead vertex, but I'm not experienced with that.

Comment: This is very similar to what I wanted but
instead of vertex color, is it possible to make it something like materials?
since vertex colors don't pass through when exported as .obj

Comment: Do you need OBJ? Or you can export as PLY with vertex color and with MeshLab export as OBJ with vertex color https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/200782/2214 BTW

Comment: If OBJ cant export vertex color I would say Face color would be the same, it means you would have to generate material per face = with object consist of 100 faces you will export object with 100 materials? It doesn't sounds good ...

Comment: Here is a script that bakes Normals to "per-face vertex color" https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27752/2214 so probably someone can modify it for UV image? I asked for you https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211578/per-face-vertex-color-from-image-texture

Comment: well, the materials don't need to be 100% accurate
They should just be like colored enough to be able to represent the following model
also, the models that I have consist of 1.7k faces only

Comment: But you don't want to use a image texture right? So there is only to use per-face vertex color or assign material per face ... in your case 1.7k materials that I even know if that is possible. Any of this solution is not about accuracy. I'm thinking if it isn't a naming confusion between us.