# Per-Face Vertex Color from Image Texture

Tags: python, add-on, vertex-colors

Is it possible to convert a UV mapped image texture into **per-face vertex color**?

I found this script that can generate [Per-face vertex color from Normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27752/2214) of 2.79, or an add-on [Bake vertex color](https://gumroad.com/l/zdgxg), but it doesn't work per-face.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWyqs.png]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It depends how often you want to do this.. it's computationally inefficient, but I'm sure an equivalent procedure would be scriptable.. Split all edges on mesh. In UV map, pivot 'Individual Origins', scale all faces to 0, so all faces sample a point. Run 'Bake Vertex Color'

Comment: I came to this through this Q https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/211511/2214 so I was curious how to ... your step with "Individual Origins" generated my Q :) BTW Scale to zero (or even with small face size) results as black for "Bake Vertex Color" add-on :)

Comment: Oh. Bother. It's a beautifully written add-on, well-commented... but it's doing quite sophisticated sampling, which is getting tangled up by 0 faces? Would 1 center-of-face sample do, for your case? (Where's @batFINGER when you need him :D)